# Writing to a File in aws S3 with spring batch

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, spring-batch

i've got assigned a task where i have to do a batch process when every half-hour this call an API for some data and this data must be stored in a s3 bucket in a different file.

i already did it by copying the data in a `BufferedOutputStream` then uploading to s3 with `uploadPart` from the sdk-java (v2) in a class extending `FlatFileItemWriter<T>`.

but i wonder if **is there another way to write to an already existing file in a bucket with a chunk process with Spring Batch?** at least to reduce the size of processing per call since the data i get from the API is growing quite fast as the original API response is getting large in size (like 1000 and more) per request.

This will be streamed in a future, but since we are in migration i need a temporary solution while the API i call gets migrated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=540395, there is no way to append to an s3 file.

Based on that, you would need to generate a new file and upload it again to replace the previous one.

Comment: aww that's too bad, i was expecting a fine more grained way to do this, because literally i'm duplicating data in memory in my implementation, and the duration is highly increasing.